Get bonds data in python
Anyone knows a way of getting trustworthy bonds data in python? I know that for stock there is yfinance package but it doesnt include bonds.
Thx

It's still mostly OTC and making data available for bonds was the reason Bloomberg turned into what it is today. So finding a trustworthy source for free is probably not possible. Generally, yfinance isn't particularly trustworthy either, and full of errors.

What data - market data price/yield & volume? Indicative - oupon&maturity?

For US treasuries, treasurydirect.gov provides a rest API: https://www.treasurydirect.gov/legal-information/developers/web-api-security/
For corporates and everything else, you need either Bloomberg or Reuters / Refinitiv / LSEG. Bloomberg used to be kind enough to provide a free API in FIGI https://bsym.bloomberg.com/api that allowed you to get some indicative data for a limited number of bonds at a time. It may have been retired.

If you are interested in just yields, you can use FRED and Pandas Datareader.
# Import the libraries

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime

# Time range

start = datetime.date(2000, 1, 1)
end = datetime.date.today()

# Import the data

yields = ['DGS3MO', 'DGS1', 'DGS10']
df_yields = pdr.DataReader(yields, 'fred', start, end)

